# What does it mean for $f_{ijkl}$ to be symmetric in the indices? And how do you define a trilinear form?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f \in \mathbb{Z}[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ be a non-singular quartic homogeneous polynomial. Assume that $$
f(\mathbf{x})=\sum_{i, j, k, \ell=1}^{n} f_{i j k \ell} x_{i} x_{j} x_{k} x_{\ell}
$$
for $f_{i j k \ell} \in \mathbb{Z}$ that are symmetric in the indices. We may then define the trilinear forms
$$
L_{i}(\mathbf{w} ; \mathbf{x} ; \mathbf{y}):=4 ! \sum_{j, k, \ell=1}^{n} f_{i j k \ell} w_{j} x_{k} z_{\ell}
$$
for $1 \leqslant i \leqslant n$.

I sadly have further issues with the topic. I have a generating function $$S(\alpha)=\sum_{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{Z}^{n} \cap[-B, B]^{n}} e(\alpha f(\mathbf{x}))$$ with $\alpha \in [0,1]$ being a real variable.
And $e(z):=e^{2\pi i z}$.
Then I don't understand how they get to this bound: $$|S(\alpha)|^{2} \leqslant \sum_{|\mathbf{w}| \leqslant B}\left|\sum_{\mathbf{x} \in \mathscr{R}(\mathbf{w})} e(\alpha(f(\mathbf{w}+\mathbf{x})-f(\mathbf{x})))\right|$$ and then also supposedly via  Cauchy's inequality to
$$
|S(\alpha)|^{4} \ll B^{n} \sum_{|\mathbf{w}|,|\mathbf{x}| \leqslant B}\left|\sum_{\mathbf{y} \in \mathscr{S}(\mathbf{w}, \mathbf{x})} e(\alpha f(\mathbf{w}, \mathbf{x} ; \mathbf{y}))\right|
$$
where
$$
f(\mathbf{w}, \mathbf{x} ; \mathbf{y}):=f(\mathbf{w}+\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y})-f(\mathbf{w}+\mathbf{y})-f(\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y})+f(\mathbf{y})
$$
and
$\mathscr{R}(\mathbf{w})$ and $\mathscr{S}(\mathbf{w}, \mathbf{x})$ are certain cubes inside $[-B, B]^{n}$, depending on the arguments.

Comment: Symmetric in the indices just means that you can permute them as you wish, e.g. $f_{1234}=f_{1423}$. Trilinear means that if you fix two of the coordinates, then the map is linear in the remaining coordinate.

Comment: Thank you for your very fast answer. The first part makes complete sense now. Do they get the $4!$ in the trilinear form also from the permutation of a fixed coordinate then or..? :)

Comment: You could put any constant instead of $4!$ and it would still be trilinear (as multiplication by a constant does not change linearity).

Comment: I do have further issues with this topic. I don't really understand how I would get to those bounds. Does it have to do with $S(\alpha)$ being a cubic exponential sum? And where would I find the needed information about Weyl differencing?